# Is it possible to make a host depend on a service in Nagios?

Tags: nagios

I've got a satellite modem I'm monitoring via Nagios, and the way it's set up now, Nagios reports the router on the other side of the satellite link as down when the modem has no signal. I'd like to make the router dependent on the service that checks the satellite signal. I could just make a second satellite host that only checks the signal, but that seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would ordinarily be implemented in nagios as a parent (modem)/ child (router) host relationship rather than a service or host dependency.

However, in your case that won't work based on the way you view--and have defined--your host check for the modem. The nagios philosophy is that for things whose purpose is to pass traffic (e.g., switch, router, modem) they are alive (up) if they are passing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. But how about the define router with `check_command` is `check_signal`, something like this:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               modem
    service_description     satellite_signal
    check_command           check-signal
    contacts                admin
}

define host {
    use                     generic-router
    host_name               router
    address                 1.2.3.4
    check_command           check-signal
    contacts                admin
}
```